# The largest Integer from n integers in python

Tags: python, list

The program must accept a integer and the list of integers then the output should be the largest possible integer from the given array of integers

```
from itertools import permutations as p
a=int(input())
print("".join(sorted(list(set(p(list(input().strip().split(" "))))))[-1]))
```

This is my code but it is not working since it takes too much of time to execute 
[image: example Output/Input]

> Execution Time Limit : 500ms

Comment: how much time should it take?

Comment: it should take a execution time of 500ms

Comment: The text in your question does not properly describe the instructions for the task. If you want to make the biggest integer by concatenating other integers, you don't need to try every single permutation. You just need to get the highest value digits towards the start of your number.

Comment: E.g. in example 1, 60 is at the beginning of the output because it starts with a 6, highest than the others. In example 2, 92 is at the beginning of the output because it starts with a 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## This was the first, naive approach:

> As others said, sorting is the only key here. As a oneliner taking
>   standard input:
>
> `print("".join(sorted(input().split(), reverse=True)))`

This works in some test cases, but fails miserably with the case `98 987`.

## This is a correct approach, at least I thought so:

> ```
> def compare(a, b): 
>     for i,j in zip_longest(a, b): 
>         if i is not None and j is not None: 
>            if i<j: 
>                return -1 
>            elif i>j: 
>                return 1 
>         if i is None: 
>             return int(a[0])-int(j) 
>         if j is None: 
>             return int(b[0])-int(i) 
>     return 0
> ```
>
> ### Testing
>
> ```
> >>> a = ['24', '26', '28', '987', '556', '214', '398', '476', '542', '192', '878', '566', '744', '232', '456', '98', '2', '4', '76', '78']
> >>> print("".join(reversed(sorted(a, key=functools.cmp_to_key(compare)))))
> 98987878787674456655654247645643982826242322214192
> >>> 98987878787674456655654247645643982826242322214192 == 98987878787674456655654247645643982826242322214192
> True
> ```
>
> So it seems to work.
>
> ### Explanation
>
> `zip_longest` is the same as `zip`, but it pads for unequal lengths.
>   Example `zip_longest("1", "12")` gives `[("1", "1"), (None, "2")]`.
>
> As long as none of the elements in the tuple are `None` everything is
>   supposed to work normally:
>
> - If `i` is smaller than `j`, then the number containing `i` -- here `a` -- must be smaller than the number containing `j` -- here `b` --
>     so we return `-1`.
> - The other way around, it's the same.
>
> So far, this is the same as the alphanumeric ordering. But what if one
>   number is `None`? Example: Take `a = 987` and `b = 98`. At one point,
>   `i` is `7` and `j` is `None`. In alphanumeric ordering, `7` would be
>   larger than `None`, `a>b`. But here, we have to take into account,
>   that the numbers will be chained, so we have to in fact check, if `7`
>   is greater than the first digit of the other number, which is `9`. `7`
>   is actually smaller, so `b` comes first.
>
> If none of the conditions are met, the numbers must be equal and `0`
>   is returned.

This worked in most test cases, but fails miserably with `98 989`.

## This is the correct solution:

```
def compare(a, b): 
    x = a+b 
    y = b+a 
    if x>y: 
        return 1 
    elif x<y: 
        return -1 
    else: 
        return 0
```

### Testing

```
In [96]: a = ["98", "987"]                                                                                           
In [97]: print("".join(reversed(sorted(a, key=functools.cmp_to_key(compare)))))                                      
98987

In [98]: a = ["989", "98"]                                                                                           
In [99]: print("".join(reversed(sorted(a, key=functools.cmp_to_key(compare)))))                                      
98998

In [100]: a = ['24', '26', '28', '987', '556', '214', '398', '476', '542', '192', '878', '566', '744', '232', '456', 
     ...: '98', '2', '4', '76', '78']                                                                                
In [101]: print("".join(reversed(sorted(a, key=functools.cmp_to_key(compare)))))                                     
98987878787674456655654247645643982826242322214192
```

They all work

### Explanation

The very first approach was too easy, the second was overcomplex. This one is the midway and actually very straight forward. Combine each pair in both possible way. Which combination yields the bigger number? That will dictate the sorting.

I hope everything is clear now and that this withstands any test case I maybe even never thought of.

Comment: It doesn't work for this case Input: 24 26 28 987 556 214 398 476 542 192 878 566 744 232 456 98 2 4 76 78   and the Expected O/P : 98987878787674456655654247645643982826242322214192   this code O/P:98798878787674456655654247645643982826242322142192

Comment: It is actually way trickier, than anybody here thought, as it turns out. I'm still thinking about it

Comment: @Tonystark I think I have it *sorted out* (haha) now

Comment: Great job, did you check for the runtime?

Comment: For the test case mentioned above, it took `31.1 µs ± 23.3 ns per loop` with `print` and `25.5 µs ± 60.2 ns` without, on my machine. Thank you very much :D

Comment: Actually this still fails on `989 98`, but I think I need a break

Comment: @Tonystark now I really can't find a test that fails

Comment: @Tonystark I'm very glad to hear that indeed :D